# Automate Mouse Movement from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2 with complete control

Tags: python, mouse

This is what I'm trying to do:

Move cursor from Start X, Y to Finish X, Y. In between the Start and Finish points, is a Red Square.

I'm trying to make a program that does this movement while checking for the condition of the red square. If it finds a red square in its path, it will terminate the mouse movement. So the cursor will be on the red square.

Something... like... This:

```
Move Cursor(x1, y1)
While cursor isn't at finish point:
      Move Cursor(x2, y2)
      if red square:
        break
```

I do not need the code to detect the red square, but I need to have a method to move the mouse and have a feature that can abruptly terminate the mouse movement.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Lets Start This:
first, you could use **pyinput**, its a realiable library I have used so many times to Control mouse and keyboard , read Here: [Pyinput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

Second, look at my line by line detailed Example Below:Your Code will look something like it

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller # importing the Function
mouse = Controller() # getting the mouse controller
########################################################################## The function you need
def moveCursor( # the Function name is not representable, personally I would have named it GlideMouseUntil()
                x1,y1, #the Start Position. type (int)
                x2,y2, #the End Position. type (int)
                intervals, #How many points on path you want to check. type (int)
                CheckerFunction #this is the function that will check for the red Square, must return True to stop, False means continue. type(func name)
             ):
    mouse.position = (x1,y1) #set the inital mouse position to the start position
    distance_x = x2-x1 #calculate the Horizontal distance between the two points
    distance_y = y2-y1 #calculate the Vertical distance between the two points
    for n in range(0, intervals+1): #for Every point on the line
        if CheckerFunction(): #Run the ckecker function
            break #if it returns True: break from the loop and exit the function , Red square Found !! YaY
        else: #if it returns False
            mouse.move(x1 + n * (distance_x/intervals), y1 + n * (distance_y/intervals)) #Calulate the Next position and go to it
        pass
    pass
##########################################################################
def checkForRedSquare(): # The function that will Check for the red Square, must return True if square is found . false if not
    if SquareIsFound:
        return True
        pass
    else:
        return False
        pass
##########################################################################
moveCursor(10,10,1000,1000, 30,checkForRedSquare) # means check 30 equally distanced point from poosition(10,10) until (1000,1000) if Square is Found in between stop
```

I am open to Any Questions
I hope that Helps, good Luck!!